# How can I remove these Hep20 tees?

Tags: plumbing-fixture

can anyone tell me how to remove these Hep20 Tees please? I want to replace with elbows and cut the lower leg off.  (I know how to seal those off thanks).  Can't upload a picture but they were fitted in 2007. They have a screw off cap and are grey, fitted to plastic and copper

Answer (score 1):

Google tells me you need a HepKey or HepKey Plus. That's the blue part in this cutaway image.

[image: Image of a HepKey release tool]

Looking at how it works, it looks like you just need a round collar that can get between the tubing and the rim of that outer ring. I would try rolling a plastic card with a heat gun and see if I could push the release ring without hunting down the tool.